# Using mapscript with ruby on rails?

Tags: references, mapscript, ruby

I want to use mapscript with rubyonrails

how should i start doing this?
can anyone point to a good tutorial on mapscript?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use this gem in your Rails application? https://github.com/sourcepole/ruby_mapscript

From the documentation:

> Ruby MapScript API extensions
>   This gem extends the SWIG MapScript API of UMN MapServer with Ruby-like > iterators and other API methods.

Comment: thanks! i did see this gem, however it is about 4 years old with only 7 stars, meaning it didnt caught, and i'd like a more "official" way.